# SVN Repository for common code -phonegap

Tags: android, ios, svn, cordova

I am creating a phonegap app which will be supported by

```
Android 
Windows phone
iOS 
BlackBerry
```

So far, main development happen on Android and all JS/HTML are copied to other platforms. Moving on, we have to keep different repositories for all the platforms for easier maintenance.

The obvious way I can think of is to create a folder for each platform and maintain the code there. But in that case, if we are modifying any www (JS/HTML/CSS/Images) contents, we will need to manually copy to all the repos.

Is there a better way to handle common files, or copying same file to 4 locations is the only way out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution would be to split your code into the following folders/repositories:

- common - contains all platform independent files
- android - contains android specific files
- windows - contains windows specific files
- ios - contains ios specific files
- blackberry - contains blackberry specific files

And then create a small script that can create a valid project out of these files by doing the following steps:

- copy all files of the `common` folder to a `target` folder
- copy the files of a platform folder (e.g. android) to the `target` folder (and overwrite existing files)
- package the target folder to an application package and deploy in on a device

So you have to change platform independent only in one location and still have the change to add platform specific code (or overwrite common code for a specific platform).

Answer (score 2):

You can use ["Externals"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) for this. An external repository allows you to include a separate repository within a given repo - so within your device-specific repositories, you can include the common "JS/HTML" repository.

We have actually stepped away from this approach, because it does mean that every time someone commits a new version in the shared repo, that change immediately propagates to the other repositories. This can cause problems managing those dependencies - so we use a build script to check out a specific version from the shared repo as part of the build process.